# hexadecimal values in masm starting with a letter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, masm

Do hexadecimal values in masm have to start with a number? If I use

```
.const

    _mmx_cons   QWORD f000000000000000h
```

I get a build error :

```
test.asm(26): error A2006: undefined symbol : f000000000000000h
```

But if I add a leading 0

```
.const

    _mmx_cons   QWORD 0f000000000000000h
```

The error vanish. Why is that? Am I sure that it represents the 64 bit value `0xf000000000000000`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hex numbers using the `h` suffix must start with a decimal digit, otherwise they would be mistaken for label names. That's why you add a leading zero if the most significant hex digit is `A`..`F`.

Leading zeroes do not affect the value or storage size requirement of the immediate. For example, it's perfectly ok to write `MOV AL, 00000001h`, because `00000001h` is exactly the same as `1`.