# How to make a register overflow using variables in Assembly Language

Tags: visual-studio-2012, assembly, x86, overflow, masm

I am learning Assembly Language (x86) and I need to figure out how to make a register overflow using only variables rather than intermediate values.

I with to overflow the `AX` register by putting FFFF into a variable, moving that variable into `AX`, and then incrementing `AX`. However, I am running into problems. First off, I go to declare a `WORD` variable like this:

```
limitReg WORD 0
```

Then later on in `.code` I do this:

```
MOV limitReg, FFFFh
MOV ax, limitReg
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error   1   error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi     /Fo"Debug\pa2.obj" /Fl"PA2.lst" /I "C:\Irvine" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Irvine\Examples\ch03\pa2.asm" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets 50
```

Can someone please help me out with learning this?

Comment: Aren't there any more error messages in the console? Some that point to the actual lines of code that fail to assemble.

Comment: @Michael Nope. The only message I get is the one stated.

Comment: In masm you load from memory like `mov ax, [limitReg]`, which loads **from** the address - instead of just loading the address itself. Also, your first instruction just doesn't exist. You can't move values around without involving a register.

Comment: The assembler should have generated a file `PA2.lst` (considering the command line option `/F1`). Please view the contents of that file; it should provide full details about what went wrong during assembly.

Comment: Please note `FFFFh` must be preceded by a zero (`0FFFFh`); see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934064/hexademical-values-in-masm-starting-with-a-letter

Comment: `limitReg WORD 0`, shouldn't that be `limitReg DW 0`?

Comment: @BoPersson `mov ax, [limitReg]` is NASM syntax (or TASM in ideal mode); MASM does not accept the brackets. And `MOV memory,immediate` has been a valid instruction ever since the original 8086. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Ruud MASM will ignore the brackets. Stylistically it's a good idea to use brackets for memory operands, so they appear different than immediate operands, but MASM makes that determination based on the type of the symbol.

Comment: @RossRidge Thanks for the correction. I totally agree brackets are preferable; I guess most of us do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"intermediate values" huh?  Did you mean "immediate"?  Memory locations are *are* intermediate values.  Using them directly (`inc [myvar]`) is usually not a good idea.  Memory is for long-term storage of variables, or when you run out of registers and need to spill one.

Terminology aside, I think I know what you're trying to do (using 16bit asm for some reason):

```
section .data
myvar: dw 0FFFFH     ; 2 bytes of storage intialized to -1

section .text
GLOBAL asmfunction
asmfunction:
    ;mov ax, myvar   ; ax = address of myvar
    mov ax, [myvar]  ; ax = contents of myvar
    inc ax
    mov [myvar], ax  ; store back to the global variable
    ret
```

Actually, in MASM syntax (rather than NASM), `mov ax, myvar` might still be a load, rather than a mov-immediate with the address.  If you want a load/store, it's definitely a good idea to always write it as  `[addr]`.  If you want the address, [you can use `mov ax, offset myvar`](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/lecture.html#I77_0180_offset_operator), which is more efficient than `lea ax, [myvar]`

Also, more simply:

```
xor ax, ax   ; zero ax (but not eax)
dec ax       ; unsigned carry from from 0 to 0xffff.
             ;  However, dec doesn't touch CF, only the other flags
```

It's common enough to talk about "overflowing" an unsigned value, but keep in mind that instructions set the x86 Carry and Overflow flags based on [unsigned carry (between 0 and 0xff...) and signed overflow (between `MIN_INT` and `MAX_INT`)](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt).